# How can i insert list as string with ansible in line in file

Tags: ansible

I have list in ansible as

```
mylist = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
```

This is ansible variable.

Now in my some file on remote host i want something like

```
lineinfile: dest=~/.config line='myvar = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]'
```

How can i do that using mylist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the list's pythonic representation as a string, you'll need to write the string to represent the list representation (brackets), and join the list's values using a delimiter (`' ,'` in the example):

```
lineinfile: dest=~/.config line="myvar = [ {{' ,'.join(myvar) }} ]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary files don't know about types etc., you want an ordinary string.

`mylist = '["test1", "test2", "test3"]'`

`lineinfile: dest=~/.config line="myvar = {{ mylist }}"`

Comment: but i can't do that , that mylist is coming from ansible , its not something which i can define , its only with debug that i can see it like that